# Action bar : get view element

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am implementing **Action bar** compoment.

my `res/menu/action_menu.xml` which holds two items to be shown on **Action Bar**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item 
          android:id="@+id/help_me"
          android:icon="@drawable/help"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item 
          android:id="@+id/log_out"
          android:icon="@drawable/logout"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

In my **Activity**:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity{

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0); 
        ...
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I would like to fetch the `@+id/help_me` icon from action bar **< item >** and **add** `onClickListener` to it, based on my above code in Activity, where and how can I fetch the `@+id/help_me` icon and add the listener ??

Answer (score 2):

you can use `menu.findItem(R.id.help_me)` and an [`OnMenuItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setOnMenuItemClickListener%28android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener%29). Bear in mind that unless you're doing anything special with the menu item, you should use the standard callbacks [built into the Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29)